# How to loop through rows and changing the reference worksheet in each cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and was just trying to figure this out.

I have a the following range CR7, CR9:CR24, CR28:CR39, CR45:CR50, CR52

Currently, each of these cells reference a value from another worksheet.

```
CR7='Trend'!CO7
CR9='Trend'!CO9
CR10='Trend'!CO10
```

This will follow the entire range.

What I was wanting to do was change the reference to 3 columns to the right.

CR7='Trend'!CO7 will then be CR7='Trend'!CR7

What I was trying to do was remove the last 3 characters after the "!" and then replace it with "RC[-3]" but I don't know what I'm doing at all. I just looked up different codes on this site and tried to piece it together, knowing that I would probably run into some obstacles because I'm new at this.

Here's the code I was trying to implement but running into an error.

```
For Each C In Range("CR7,CR9:CR24,CR28:CR39,CR45:CR50,CR52")
   C.Value = Left(C.Value, InStr(C.Value, "!") - 1)
   C.Value = C.Value & "RC[-3]"
Next
```

Any suggestions on how to get this corrected or is there a better way in doing this? Thanks in advance for looking into this!!

Comment: Use `Range("CR7,CR9:CR24,CR28:CR39,CR45:CR50,CR52").Replace "CO","CR"`

Comment: Thank you Scott! Let me try that out. Is there a way to make it dynamic, so that every month when I use this template, the columns shift to the right by 3. So the next month will then be CU. The following month will be CX etc.

Comment: Scott, I was trying to be vague with the tab name. It's actually CR7='CORP Trend'!CO7. So when I do the replacement it errors out because the (CO) in CORP is replaced with a CR and not just the cell reference. Sorry I should have caught this earlier.

Comment: You can do it dynamically by either pressing a button, or better yet, build a udf within the formula, I assume you have a pivot header name for it to be triggered? As for common language, this cell equals to the revenue in the trend sheet?

Comment: `Range("CR7,CR9:CR24,CR28:CR39,CR45:CR50,CR52").Replace "!CO","!CR"` will only change the column.  As to dynamic.  That is a bigger change.  I do not have the time to write that out.  someone else may.

Comment: That's correct Sgdva, it's just bringing over the revenue from the trend sheet. The header is just the month, for example it's Aug-22. Then next month the header will b Sept-22. At the moment they are just formulas referencing the trend sheet and was wanting to use vba to change that reference, so I don't really have any triggers set up right now. I can do what Scott has provided because I understand that code but udfs and such, is way above my knowledge of vba at the moment haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

As stated in the comments, since you are looking for a specific header, the solution might be faster as follows:

Assuming the headers are in Sheet 1 as follows

| Jan-22 (IE:actual data is 01-01-2022) | Feb-22 | Mar-22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 30 | 60 |
| 20 | 40 | 70 |

Where A1 = Jan-22, B2= Feb-22, etc.

Just use a combination of index and match, seems like you need to bring the row at the same level, so it will be as follows:

Set a referece in your formula to where you will have the criteria to look: In this example will be A1

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$C,ROW(),MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))
```

I'll explain:

Index will bring the column where you want the data, in this case will be the data under the month (Col A), seems like the row should be at the same level, so we will say the row will be equal to where the formula row is being casted, that's why the row(), finally, it will be in where the column matches the criteria that you want where the header is found, if you need an offset even after finding the column name, just sum it up at that part

```
MATCH($A$1,Sheet1!$1:$1,0) + 3
```

***Demo***:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I think this will work, I will try this and see if I run into any issues!